# Recurring start of process in case process isn't started on Linux

Tags: linux

I need to create an application that performs reconnect to WiFi and VPN from Ubuntu desktop if case any of these connections drop. I know there are numerous ways to do it via system settings and ifup/down tools, but all of these seem to disrupt the other system parts like Network Manager, etc.

That is why I decided my application will check and do stuff if needed. But there may be an even when some circumstances led to my application not being started or had been terminated. I need a way to set the system to perform a recurring check to see if my application process is running, and if not, start it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what version of Ubuntu you are using;

Prior to 14.10 Ubuntu used [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) it can be used to monitor a service and restart it if it fails (respawn)

From 14.10 onwards Ubuntu is using [systemd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) which can also monitor a service and restat it if it fails (Restart=on-failure)